# Subconsulta con LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

El problema consiste en que la subconsulta no obtiene nada: Lo que deseo obtener en la columna [ rs ] es el nombre del banco, actualmente esta retornando null.

[image: QUERY SQL Y RESULTADO DE LA QUERY]

---

```
   SELECT ta.id
    ,ta.idTarea 
    ,ta.idConsignacion
    ,nomBanco.rs
    FROM tarea_actividad AS ta
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT cl.razon_social  rs,
       cg.bancoDestino  cb 
       FROM consignacion cg INNER JOIN cliente  cl ON (cg.bancoDestino=cl.id)) AS nomBanco 
    ON (ta.idConsignacion=nomBanco.cb)
    WHERE ta.idTarea=333
```

[image: relaciones mysql]

en la tabla clientes.razon_social hace referencia a los nombres de los bancos: bbva, popular, bancolombia.

y clientes.constitucion: es la manera de diferenciar si el cliente es una empresa o una persona: natural/juridica

Aqui esta la estructura de las tablas

http://rextester.com/LULK49381

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Roca. Puedes explicar qué es lo que tratas de obtener? Poon un ejemplo del resultado de la consulta que esperas y què estás obteniendo ahora. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: @roca33scorpio debes publicar las estructuras de las tablas para poder ayudarte

Comment: pues me imagino que no hace mucho sentido que la condición del inner join sea entre el id del banco de destino y el id de cliente....

Comment: @Lamak opino lo mismo pero hay que ver la estructuras de las tablas para saber que es lo que quiere unir

Comment: @Frankenstainero sí, pero si tuviera que adivinar el por qué el left join entrega sólo nulls sería porque la condición del inner join nunca se cumple....porque está igualando el banco con el cliente

Comment: @Lamak opino lo mismo porque no hay coincidencia de datos para que le traiga lo que quiere

Comment: Lo que más ayudaría (a ti sobre todo) y a nosotros para dar una respuesta adecuada, es que expliques la lógica de tu diseño, o sea, *quién se relaciona con quién* en tus tablas. Estoy casi seguro de que los `JOIN` se pueden hacer de una forma más sencilla, pero se necesita que plantees la lógica del programa.

Comment: Lo único que puedo decir al ver solo lo que nos has compartido, es que muy posiblemente la subconsulta no obtenga datos, compruébalo previamente y nos cuentas.

Comment: Revisar [answer].

Comment: ta.idConsignacion=nomBanco.cb estoy 100% que esta mal, no deberia ser nomBanco.id? y eso que ni estoy mirando si el query es logico.

Answer (score 1):

Sres, buenas noches!
Quiero compartir la respuesta a la pregunta que habia formulado, tal vez le pueda servir a otra persona que este iniciando como es mi caso. Muchas gracias a todos los que comentaron, me dieron pistas para la solucion.

SOLUCION 1: 
[image: CONSULTA 1]

```
SELECT nomBanco.t0 AS id, nomBanco.t3 AS idTarea, nomBanco.t1 AS idConsignacion, cliente.razon_social AS rs
FROM (SELECT tarea_actividad.id t0,tarea_actividad.idConsignacion t1, consignacion.bancoDestino t2, tarea_actividad.idTarea t3
      FROM tarea_actividad 
      INNER JOIN consignacion ON tarea_actividad.idConsignacion=consignacion.id) AS nomBanco
INNER JOIN cliente ON nomBanco.t2 = cliente.id
WHERE nomBanco.t3=333
```

SOLUCION 2: 
[image: CONSULTA 2]

```
SELECT ta.id
,ta.idTarea 
,ta.idConsignacion
,nomBanco.rs
FROM tarea_actividad AS ta
INNER JOIN (SELECT cliente.razon_social rs,consignacion.id AS idecong FROM consignacion INNER JOIN cliente ON consignacion.bancoDestino=cliente.id) AS nomBanco ON ta.idConsignacion=nomBanco.idecong 
WHERE ta.idTarea=333
```

Comment: Puedes [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).